# td element with 2 text inputs excessively wide

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css (and stackoverflow) and I'm trying to create a form using a table to organize the inputs (I know, not totally kosher).  I'm using a table so I can organize the labels, inputs, and descriptions into columns to keep everything aligned.  Everything looked great until I needed to put 2 text inputs into the input column (worked fine for a group of radio buttons).  Once I did this, that column became excessively wide.  Inspecting the elements with Chrome Developer Tools only shows that the corresponding table cell has an excessively large content area.

Any ideas how to get the width under control?

Here is a MWE of my problem.

```css
form {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: table;
}

th, td {
  margin: 2em auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

th + td  {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"]{
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MWE Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body> 
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="get"  action="http://usesas01.wlgore.com/sasweb/cgi-bin/broker.exe?" target="_blank">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>   
              Specification(s)*
          </th>
          <td>
            <input id="lsl" name="lsl" type="text" class="spec">
            <input id="usl" name="usl" type="text" class="spec">
          </td>
          <td>
            Lower and/or upper specification limits
          </td>    
        </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is 'excessively wide'? It looks kind of okay to me https://jsfiddle.net/ca8pt7c5/

Comment: In full screen, the td element is about 350px wide and the text inputs are about 70px wide.  I want the td element to only be as wide as the the 2 input boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you can give the `<input>` a fixed width, or a max-width.

**[Updated Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dhy2qp0a/)**

```css
form {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: table;
}
th, td {
  margin: 2em auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
}
th + td  {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap; /*no wrap*/
}
input[type="text"]{
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 30px; /*no % width*/
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="http://usesas01.wlgore.com/sasweb/cgi-bin/broker.exe?" target="_blank">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Specification(s)*
      </th>
      <td>
        <input id="lsl" name="lsl" type="text" class="spec">
        <input id="usl" name="usl" type="text" class="spec">
      </td>
      <td>
        Lower and/or upper specification limits
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky fix, you can add a class to another one of the columns and assign it `width:100%;` so that it takes up the space that the original middle column took:

```css
form {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f4f7f8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.absorb {
  width: 100%;
}
th,
td {
  margin: 2em auto;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
th + td {
  text-align: center;
}
input[type="text"] {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 46%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="http://usesas01.wlgore.com/sasweb/cgi-bin/broker.exe?" target="_blank">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Specification(s)*
      </th>
      <td style="background:lightblue;">
        <input id="lsl" name="lsl" type="text" class="spec">
        <input id="usl" name="usl" type="text" class="spec">
      </td>
      <td class="absorb">
        Lower and/or upper specification limits
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```